# how to know which form called the fonction in delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a lot of Forms, and in one Form I use printing. All other Forms can call this printing Form.

In addition, every Form has different objects, some of them have `TDBGrid` and `Filtered` option, and some of them don't. I tried to check before printing if there's a `Filter`. I did some code and I get a result, but this didn't work with all Forms because every Form have a different name, as everyone knows.

My question is, how to know which Form clicked the printing button and use it?

//on form is 1

```
form1.dbgrid.somecode
```

for second form

```
form2.stringgrid.somecode
```

How can I know which Form, and can I save the object's name in a table in the database?

Comment: Pass the clicking Form as a parameter to the printing Form, and then it can scan through that clicking Form's `Components` for specific types of components as needed, like `TDBGrid`.